# I Can Do Anything!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm a serial killer
But I'm not on the lam.
I put nips onto noses
'Cause I don't give a darn.

I've an eye for a card game,
I help flats for the lasses.
Like to scare in October,
Knock kids right on their bottoms.

Fan favorite in baseball,
But I fly with the Brits.
I'm spicy and cheesy, but
I won't give you trots.

I cut like a knife,
But I'm bad news for trucking.
I love calisthenics
Which can help with your yoga.

What am I?

Comment: I can't help thinking of Jason (Serial Killer, October, Baseball, the knife... :) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have quite every line figured out yet, but I'm fairly sure you're

> Jack

I Can Do Anything!

> Jack of all trades

I'm a serial killer

> Jack the ripper

But I'm not on the lam.

I put nips onto noses

> Jack Frost. Thanks @SuperWild1

'Cause I don't give a darn.

I've an eye for a card game,

> The jack is a card with an eye.

I help flats for the lasses.

> Car jack. Thanks @SuperWild1

Like to scare in October,

> Jack o' Lanterns

Knock kids right on their bottoms.

> Jack in the box

Fan favorite in baseball,

> Jackie Robinson, or Cracker Jack

But I fly with the Brits.

> Union jack

I'm spicy and cheesy, but

> Pepperjack

I won't give you trots.

I cut like a knife,

> Maybe a jackknife or lumberjack

But I'm bad news for trucking.

> <s>A car jack can be used to steal a truck.</s> Jackknifing. Thanks @SuperWild1

I love calisthenics

> Jumping jacks

Which can help with your yoga.

Comment: Very nimble answer, and quick, too!